# External AOP (like AspectJ) weaving for .net?

Tags: c#, .net, aop

I want to do trace logging in a program by weaving in proxies in the IL.  What are some current frameworks that are good for this?

(Most of the ones I've Googled are either old or don't have documentation, that is why I ask.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most common thing I've come across for doing this type of thing in .Net is [PostSharp](https://web.archive.org/web/20110428114309/http://www.sharpcrafters.com/solutions). It has been around for a while and is well-known. It has a [specific example](https://web.archive.org/web/20110509045600/http://www.sharpcrafters.com/solutions/logging) for how to inject logging on its website.

**EDIT**

Since I originally posted this answer, it looks like PostSharp has moved to a [new site](https://www.postsharp.net).

Comment: As there seems to be quite a bit of enthusiasm for this particular tool, maybe I'll drop $35 on it and try it out.

Comment: Both website links mentioned in the post seem to not be available. Is it just me?

Comment: @AurghoBhattacharjee I've just updated the answer.

Comment: Thanks so much! I did find that they're recommending metalama but started reading details and forgot to come back and report details back then.

Answer (score 2):

You've got it! Checkout the NKalore project @ 
http://aspectsharpcomp.sourceforge.net/

It has an AOP grammar which mirrors AspectJ (pointcut, aspect, thisJoinPoint, before, etc). On the flip side there is no VS.NET support although it has a command line compiler.

Answer (score 1):

[CciSharp](http://ccisamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=CciSharp&referringTitle=Home), although it's not as mature as postsharp.

If you are open to a dynamic proxy instead of code weaving then both [LinFu](http://code.google.com/p/linfu/) and Castle have implementations, but I'm guessing since you asked about weavers specifically you knew that.

Answer (score 1):

Spring.Net framework also has an AOP stack: http://www.springframework.net/doc-latest/reference/html/aop-quickstart.html

Answer (score 0):

[Postsharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) I think is the more mature solution, not open source, although

Comment: Older versions of PostSharp were open source. The source of version 1.5.x can still be downloaded from the PostSharp website.