# AOP snippet: is this Aspectj?

Tags: .net, aop

I encountered the following snippet about AOP. Can someone tell me what programming language is that?

```
  public aspect MyAspect
    {
      // Define a pointcut matched by all methods in the application whose name begins with
      // Get and accepting no arguments. (There are many other ways to define criteria.)
      public pointcut allGetMethods ():
             call (* Get*() );

      // Define an advice to run before any join points that matches the specified pointcut.
      before(): allGetMethods()
      {
        // Do your cross-cutting concern stuff here
        // for example, log about the method being executed
        .
        .
        .
      }
    }
```

---

is it AspectJ?
or there is no such laguage?

Comment: [AOP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) is not so much a "programming language" as a paradigm, and it does look like the pointcut-model (and syntax) used with [AspectJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AspectJ). However, since this is tagged .NET, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5574357/external-aop-like-aspectj-weaving-for-net

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is [AspectJ](http://eclipse.org/aspectj/).